# What is wrong with this wpdb update?

Tags: wpdb

I've read a lot of documentation tonight, can't see why this isn't working. Obviously something I'm missing.

```
$newstr = "18,19";
$defid = 1;
$table = "wp_tablename";
$data = "array( 'somecol' => '".$newstr."' )";
$where = "array( 'id' => ".$defid." )";

if ($wpdb->update( $table, $data, $where) === FALSE)
{
    echo "failure";
}
else
{
    echo "success";
}
```

Comes up false every time. Any clues? What am i missing here? I did try using format_where and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

you're creating the `$data` and `$where` values as strings, not arrays.

this:

```
$data = "array( 'somecol' => '".$newstr."' )";
$where = "array( 'id' => ".$defid." )";
```

should be:

```
$data = array( 'somecol' => $newstr );
$where = array( 'id' => $defid );
```

Comment: LoL. Yep sure am. That's probably it. Thanks! It's been a long day. ;)

Comment: Well that didn't fix it after all. when fixing those two lines it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 'identical' operator `===`, use simply `if ($wpdb->update(.......) {.......}` because [a boolean value is passed on to a control structure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). See [PHP Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). See Milo's answer for strings and arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I did get it working. All was well when i used format and format_where in wpdb->update. I guess the first time i used it I had the formats wrong so it wasn't finding the row to update. Thanks to Milo for pointing out the string issue. All is good now.